# Select minimum values of records in database where a condition is satisfied with django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following model

```
class Lances(models.Model):
    licitante = models.CharField(...)
    valor_prop = models.DecimalField(...)
    momento = models.DateTimeField(...)
    flag = models.CharField(...)
    situacao = models.CharField(...)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

supose that my database have this state

[image]

What I want is a query with django orm that returns the minimmum value of each `licitante` ie. `("Katálysis Comércio, Locação e Serviços em Equipamentos de Laboratório LTDA", 116000.0000,), ("AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES BRASIL LTDA", 117000.0000), ("PERKINELMER DO BRASIL LTDA.", 128500.0000)`

I have tried ordering by `valor_prop` and then select distinct `licitante`.

```
queryset = Lances.objects.filter(item=355, situacao='').order_by('valor_prop').distinct('licitante').values_list('licitante', 'valor_prop')
```

But no luck.

Is there a way to return the minimum value of each `licitante` in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` for this:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Lances.objects.values('licitante').annotate(min_valor_prop=Min('valor_prop')).values_list('licitante', 'min_valor_prop')
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values)

Comment: I just needed to close one parenthesis and add the filters to work as I want. Thank you very much! I will read more about aggregations.